# Difference between "linear in" and "proportional to"?

Tags: performance, data-structures, queue, space, space-complexity

A programming assignment was explicitly changed from

> use space **proportional to** the number of items currently in the queue

to

> use space **linear in** the number of items currently in the queue

what is the difference?

Comment: A constant term.   y = 5x+3 is linear in x (if x goes from 1 to 2 to 3, y increases by 5 each time), but not proportional to x (if x doubles - increases from 1 to 2 - y does not double.)

Comment: There is no difference between linear and proportional. On a second thought, yes, no other difference except for the one pointed by Jonathan.

Comment: Close-voters -  "opinion based?"  It may or may not be on-topic, but it's certainly not opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by `Jonathan Dursi` in the comment, there is a subtle difference between ***linear in*** and ***proportional to***.

Linear means a given parameter varies with the change in the other parameter,where there may be constant term difference too.

Ex :- y = 5x +3 , here y varies linearly with x and is 3 more than 5 times of x.

So, dependent on 5 times of x(power=1),not on other powers of x is the commonness between them. But, the presence of +3 makes it linear and not proportional.

To make y proportional to x, y must be equal to `y = kx`, where k is some real number. There shouldn't be any constant term in the form of addition/subtraction/exponentiation. Constants are permitted as a form of product/divisor.